# kylin.sh command

Tags: command-line, bash, hadoop, kylin

I have been trying to install Kylin and after I tried to execute the command `Kylin.sh start`, I get the following error.

I can successfully run hadoop, hbase and hive from the root.

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
KYLIN_HOME is set to /usr/local/kylin
cat: /usr/local/kyli: No such file or directory
cat: /conf/kylin.properties: No such file or directory
-mkdir: Not enough arguments: expected 1 but got 0
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -mkdir [-p] <path> ...
failed to create , Please make sure the user has right to access
```

Comment: First of all, Kylin is an Ubuntu version, specific for China. So what is `Kylin.sh` and where did you get it ? Second, how does hadoop relate to your question ? There's a lack of information and clarity in your post. Please explain

Comment: @Serg I think he is referring to this [kylin](https://github.com/apache/kylin)

Comment: @Anwar well, lets hear from OP first if this is really what they're asking about